# Bootstrap button color not working, but working in jsfiddle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The button color is not blue when i use the `btn-info` class, but works fine when i tried in jsfiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>my app</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ripples.min.css">

</head>
<body>  

<!-- carousel code here -->

<a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Click here</a>

</body>
</html>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y6Lp.png)

Comment: Inspect the element and see which styles affect it.

Comment: the `btn-info` class is crossed out completely and there is a `.btn:not(.btn-raised).btn-info {color:#03a9f4;}` which is affecting my button, it is changing the text-colour, whenever i change `btn-info` to some other class, only the text color changes. the background remains the same.

Comment: Without seeing an example, your relevant CSS code or linking the actual jsfiddle we cannot really assist you. The HTML seems fine, but this is primarily a CSS problem.

Comment: the button i get : http://i.imgur.com/kBw2pJV.png and the button i should get : https://mdbootstrap.com/components/cards/ in the "wave effect" section

Comment: i havent added any css of my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are conflict between the material-bootstrap and bootstrap stylesheets. Try commenting one ans leave the other one, it should work. And if you do not want that way ,try manually via CSS coding, try the following:

```
.btn-info {
color: #fff;
background-color: #5bc0de;
border-color: #46b8da;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

> `"background-color:#000;"`

for example on .btn-info ?

Comment: yes i did (using `!important`) and it works, the problem is default bootstrap colors are not working at all. not only with the buttons, but all other components.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problem with your bootstrap file try using these `cdns`.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Working fine here**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>my app</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ripples.min.css">

</head>
<body>  

<!-- carousel code here -->

<a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Click here</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes actually, i got that. thank you very much for your answer. but the cdns you provided me are the same as i used. the actual problem was with different version of bootstrap and bootstrap-material. a bit different from what you suggested, but thank you anyways.